# Hover state still active after mouse leaves div

Tags: html, css, hover

I am experiencing a weird issue where the hover state is still being hovered after the mouse leaves the div. To see this hover over the picture. I tried inspecting but I can't figure it out.

Youtube video https://youtu.be/PX8psGOTbNM

Not working on Wordpress: http://sogomarketingagency.com/test-3/

Works fine on CodePen: http://codepen.io/CookieFresh89/pen/emLXEK

I have tried deactivating all plugins and reverting back to original theme and am still getting this problem.

The Code:

```css
.modal {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 185px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.modal-about > label {
  background: #07B288;
  border-radius: .3em;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 0.50em 1.0em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.55s;
          transition: all 0.55s;
}
.modal-about input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: 130px;
  z-index: -10;
}
@media (min-width: 43.75em) {
  .modal-about input {
    right: 50px;
  }
}
.modal__overlay {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -800;
}
.modal__box {
  padding: 1em .75em;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 90%;
}
@media (min-height: 37.5em) {
  .modal__box {
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -80%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -80%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -80%);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 50em) {
  .modal__box {
    padding: 1.75em;
  }
}
.modal__box label {
  background: #07B288;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
  right: .5em;
  top: .5em;
  width: 1.5em;
}
.modal__box h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
}
.modal__box h2 {
  color: #07B288;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.modal__box hr {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: #E8E8E8;
}
.modal__box p {
  text-align: left;
}

.modal__overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
      -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
          transform: scale(0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
          transition: all 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

input:checked ~ .modal__overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
          transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  z-index: 800;
}

input:focus + label {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.97);
      -ms-transform: scale(0.97);
          transform: scale(0.97);
}
.about-name-h1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.about-wrapper {
    width: 185px;
    height: 227px;
    position: relative;
}
.about-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  padding: 40px 0px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
.about-overlay:hover {
  padding: 70px 0px;
}
.about-wrapper:hover .about-overlay {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.about-name, .about-overlay {
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.about-name {
    padding: 15px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    border-top: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #ffffff;
    margin:0px;
    width: 183px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.about-name:hover {
    background: #07B288;
    color: #fff;
}

.avatar-frame {
    border: 2px solid #07B288;
}
.avatar-frame, .avatar-frame img {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
    /* Saf3+, Chrome */
    border-radius: 60px;
    /* Opera 10.5, IE 9 */
    /*-moz-border-radius: 30px;  Disabled for FF1+ */
}
```

```html
<div class="about-wrapper">
    <img src="http://sogomarketingagency.com/wp-content/uploads/garry-about-president.jpg" alt="polaroid" />
    <div class="about-overlay">
        <h3>Founder</h3>

        <div class="modal-about">
            <input id="modal-about" type="checkbox" name="modal-about" tabindex="1">
            <label for="modal-about">View Profile</label>
            <div class="modal__overlay">
                <div class="modal__box">
                    <label for="modal-about">&#10006;</label>
                    <div class="avatar-frame">
                        <img src="http://sogomarketingagency.com/wp-content/uploads/garry-about-me-president-circle.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h1 class="about-name-h1">Garry Howell</h1>

                    <h2>Founder</h2>

                    <hr>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac laoreet elit. Phasellus dignissim purus vitae urna cursus, quis congue ligula tristique. Ut nec blandit risus. Donec at orci ut justo venenatis viverra. Suspendisse in volutpat lacus. In enim est, dapibus eget ipsum sed, suscipit ultrices diam.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<h4 class="about-name">Garry Howel</h4>
```

Comment: When I put your code in http://htmledit.squarefree.com/ it seems to work. Did I miss something?

Comment: Your `.modal__overlay` div element is next to the image that you are hovering – it is not visible due to `opacity:0`, but it is still there – and therefor hovering over it means the parent element _is_ in hover state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `div.modal__overlay` expands `div.about-wrapper` which creates a wider area to trigger `:hover`.

**Edit:** As mentioned by CBroe, descendants trigger the hover states of their ancestors. Since `div.modal__overlay` is `position:fixed`, it effectively creates a second hover area *for* but *outside of* `div.about-wrapper`.

I had success by adding `visibility` to the toggle for `div.modal__overlay`:

```css
.modal__overlay {
  opacity:0;
  visibility:hidden;
  ...
}

input:checked ~ .modal__overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility:visible;
  ...
}
```

However, I'm not sure *why* this helps, because elements hidden by `visibility:hidden` are [still supposed to affect layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) (i.e. take up space). So, if it creates a bigger `:hover` area with `opacity:0`, shouldn't it do the same with `visibility:hidden`? Maybe someone can help clarify this behavior.

**Edit:** More insight from Cbroe in the comments, below.

---

I built a demonstration of the difference, below. Try hovering over the blue area for box #1. Then try hovering over the same area on box #2, which is `visibility:hidden`.

```css
div.container {
  position:relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}
div.prop {
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #0CC;
}
div.prop.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}
div.container:hover {
  background-color: #F00;
}

div.container p {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>BOX #1</p>
  <div class="prop"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>BOX #2</p>
  <div class="prop invisible"></div>
</div>
```

---

And here is my working version of your code:

```css
.modal {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 185px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.modal-about > label {
  background: #07B288;
  border-radius: .3em;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 0.50em 1.0em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.55s;
          transition: all 0.55s;
}
.modal-about input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: 130px;
  z-index: -10;
}
@media (min-width: 43.75em) {
  .modal-about input {
    right: 50px;
  }
}
.modal__overlay {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -800;
}
.modal__box {
  padding: 1em .75em;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 90%;
}
@media (min-height: 37.5em) {
  .modal__box {
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -80%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -80%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -80%);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 50em) {
  .modal__box {
    padding: 1.75em;
  }
}
.modal__box label {
  background: #07B288;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
  right: .5em;
  top: .5em;
  width: 1.5em;
}
.modal__box h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
}
.modal__box h2 {
  color: #07B288;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.modal__box hr {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: #E8E8E8;
}
.modal__box p {
  text-align: left;
}

.modal__overlay {
  opacity:0;
  visibility:hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
      -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
          transform: scale(0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
          transition: all 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

input:checked ~ .modal__overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility:visible;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
          transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  z-index: 800;
}

input:focus + label {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.97);
      -ms-transform: scale(0.97);
          transform: scale(0.97);
}
.about-name-h1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.about-wrapper {
    width: 185px;
    height: 227px;
    position: relative;
}
.about-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  padding: 40px 0px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
.about-overlay:hover {
  padding: 70px 0px;
}
.about-wrapper:hover .about-overlay {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.about-name, .about-overlay {
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.about-name {
    padding: 15px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    border-top: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #ffffff;
    margin:0px;
    width: 183px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.about-name:hover {
    background: #07B288;
    color: #fff;
}

.avatar-frame {
    border: 2px solid #07B288;
}
.avatar-frame, .avatar-frame img {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
    /* Saf3+, Chrome */
    border-radius: 60px;
    /* Opera 10.5, IE 9 */
    /*-moz-border-radius: 30px;  Disabled for FF1+ */
}
```

```html
<div class="about-wrapper">
    <img src="http://sogomarketingagency.com/wp-content/uploads/garry-about-president.jpg" alt="polaroid" />
    <div class="about-overlay">
        <h3>Founder</h3>

        <div class="modal-about">
            <input id="modal-about" type="checkbox" name="modal-about" tabindex="1">
            <label for="modal-about">View Profile</label>
            <div class="modal__overlay">
                <div class="modal__box">
                    <label for="modal-about">&#10006;</label>
                    <div class="avatar-frame">
                        <img src="http://sogomarketingagency.com/wp-content/uploads/garry-about-me-president-circle.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h1 class="about-name-h1">Garry Howell</h1>

                    <h2>Founder</h2>

                    <hr>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac laoreet elit. Phasellus dignissim purus vitae urna cursus, quis congue ligula tristique. Ut nec blandit risus. Donec at orci ut justo venenatis viverra. Suspendisse in volutpat lacus. In enim est, dapibus eget ipsum sed, suscipit ultrices diam.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<h4 class="about-name">Garry Howel</h4>
```

Comment: It does not so much “expand” the hovering area of the element, it rather creates a different and “independent” hover area outside of the element, because it is position:fixed. Descendant elements trigger the hover state of their DOM ancestors, whether they have a “visible relationship” or not.

Comment: And while I could not find it explicitly specified anywhere whether elements with `visibility:hidden` are not supposed to trigger `:hover`, it seems to be consensus between browsers not to have them do that. It kinda makes sense, because you would not expect something that you can’t even see to react to your mouse pointer being over it … OK, you could argue the same for elements with `opacity:0`, but opacity is trickier in that regard, because it might not be absolutely 0, but .1 or .01 – hard to determine from which point on an element should be considered “(in-)visible” in that regard.

Comment: @CBroe That makes sense. I didn't realize that descendants can create separate hover areas for their ancestors [like that](http://jsfiddle.net/rcbysc5z/). Thanks for clarifying.